# How to sort posts in a custom post type by title in ascending order by default?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization, sort, wp-list-table

So I am using a custom post type to create a listing of businesses. Each post made, contains information about each business. The title of each post is the name of the business.

When I go to the menu created by the custom post type, I receive a standard listing of posts. (or in this particular case, a listing of business names). The posts show in a random order (or possibly being sorted by date on default?)

How can I allow for my posts to be listed in alphabetical ascending order by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `pre_get_posts`:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','wpse56753_businesses_default_order');
function wpse56753_businesses_default_order( $query ){
    if( 'business' == $query->get('post_type') ){
        if( $query->get('orderby') == '' )
            $query->set('orderby','title');

        if( $query->get('order') == '' )
            $query->set('order','ASC');
    }
}
```

Comment: @MichaelEcklund It's Stephen, what do you expect? :-)